# Heating water L-shaped house

Tags: natural-gas, tankless

I installed a tankless gas hwh but it takes forever to get hot water in two of the three bathrooms. I am wasting water.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Do not think there are any easy/cheap solutions.  Cheapest with pipe insulation will only keep the water hot in the pipes for a bit, will have cold water by morning.  Don't think a recirculating pump will work with tankless heater.  Probably the only thing that would work is to have heaters close to the bathrooms.  Maybe a real plumber will have better idea.

Comment: Replace the tankless with a tanked and put in a recirculating pump. Add smaller point of use electric or gas heaters.

Comment: Recirculation plumbing is what's commonly used to keep hot water readily available at all places. To really get it right, it has to be designed into the plumbing at installation.   There are retrofit possibilities, def. not perfect.  They circulate the hot water back thru the cold water, very slowly where installed.   If you went this route, install it furthest away from the tankless.  Also, do some research, not all tankless WH play well with recirc.

Comment: If you installed this tankless WH in the same location as a tank was, then you would not waste any more water than formerly.  However, some stretched out houses where I live were originally fitted with two tank WHs, and if both tanks would be replaced by a single tankless WH (or a single tank WH), then there could be a long delay for hot water in part of the house. What was your prior WH setup?

Comment: Some people call a tankless WH an "instant" WH and are under the mistaken impression that they will get hot water immediately at any delivery point. This is not the case for a remote (whole house) tankless WH. A point of use WH will provide hot water instantly, and this leads some to think that the remote tankless WH will also provide this.

Comment: There are ways to add a pumped circulation loop with a small tanked water heater but your cold water will be warm/ hot depending on the cycle of the recirculating system.

Comment: @crp659 there are tankless WHs that recirculate and even have integral pumps. The OP should state make and model of their tankless WH.

Comment: In old design houses hot water piped to a bathroom lavatory leads to water and energy waste. To get a few cups of warm water to wash face or brush teeth or shave can require a gallon to be wasted.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to consider point-of-use (POU) heaters in some locations. My house has a "C" shape, with the water heater above the bedrooms. We've been working on the kitchen and added a small tank water heater under the kitchen sink. There are small tankless versions as well. There's a couple of ways to play it.

**Inline**

You hook the water heater to the hot water line that exists. When you start off, you'll pull from your POU heater, but still use your main heater as well. If you went with a POU tank, this makes more sense. Still, your main heater will kick on, even if the hot water never reaches the POU heater.

**Standalone**

Hook the water line to the cold line (you can buy a T splitter to hook both the faucet and heater to this). This means only the POU heater will give you hot water. For a tank, this is more of a challenge (when you're out of hot water you need to wait on the heater), but a POU tankless won't have an issue here.

**The catch**

Electric is the most common kind of POU heater because you probably have power nearby. The key is having *enough*. Tankless might need 240v and way more than 15 amps (some take 30A 120v). Tanks need much more space and take a while to recover, but can live under 15 amps with a smaller tank (larger tanks would need up to 20 amps). Gas POU does exist, but they're far less DIY friendly because you need both incoming gas and external exhaust.

Answer (score 0):

If you are merely concerned with the waste of water, then a recirculation loop can conserve water while getting the tankless to kick on and get water to the far-away locations. As with any recirculation loop for domestic hot water, lots of insulation on the lines is good. That would be something along the lines of *push a button, water's hot in a minute or two* or whatever it takes.

Relocating the water heater to be more central, or using two, each closer to a point of use if that can't be done, may be an option, but is harder (or at least costs more) with gas due to having to run gas lines and exhaust.

Depending on how long "forever" takes, and how long the pipes are, there might be [a problem with an existing anti-scald valve](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/245628/18078) causing the bulk of your problem or making it worse. In which case finding and fixing those might greatly reduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do right now to save water in showering is to collect the initial gallon or two of cold water in a bucket and keep that in the bathroom to flush the toilet.